# How to find NAND logic with the help of full adder?

Tags: nand

> Obtain a NAND logic diagram of a single full-adder from the Boolean
> functions:
>
> - C= xy+xz+yz
> - S= C’(x+y+z)+xyz

I didn't understand the question. What  do I have to do here? Do I have to simplify the equations into NAND logic type equations then draw the diagram?

Comment: Sounds like it!

Comment: If you have trouble starting, remember that to implement a function with NAND gates it requires the function to be in sum-of-products form (SOP-form). Your function \$ C\$ is already in that form, so you can go ahead and make a NAND gate implementation from the get go.

Comment: If you are not sure what is expected for a homework question then you really, really should ask the instructor. The instructor may want you to use a particular method or show your work in a particular way.

Answer (score 1):

to design a Logic circuit with nand gates you need your equations in the form of a Sum of products, the equation for C is in the form you need, but the S equation is not, you need to expand the equation to get the desired form:

```
S = C’(x+y+z)+xy
S = C’x+C’y+C’z+xy
```

Now that you have the equations in the form you want you proceed to design the circuit having in mind that a plus in the equation is a logic OR gate and that a multiplication is an AND gate.

Now as the equations are in the form of sum of products, you can use NAND gates instead of AND gates, OR gates, and Logic Inverters.

This is the Final Circuit and the time table

Circuit with AND and OR gates:
[image: Circuit with AND and OR gates]

Circuit with NAND gates:
[image]

Time Table:
[image: Tieme Table]